# Is Gnosis Safe supported on BSC testnet?

Tags: gnosis-safe, contract-upgrading

My company is building a Dapp application that will be deployed on the Binance smart chain (BSC).

We plan to deploy our Dapp on the bsc-testnet first and need to test our smart contracts with Gnosis Safe.

I don't see any documentation for testnets, or bsc-testnet.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Where do we start?